# How to create a folder recursively in an existing tree of folders (in each existing folder)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, recursion

I'm trying to create a new folder in an existing tree with :

```
find /home/a/Desktop/MyCycles/DavidSilver -type d -exec sh -c '(cd {} && mkdir bin)' ';'
```

In Ubuntu , but I get an infinite loop of

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘bin’: File exists
```

Which BTW is not true , since the folder doesn't exist in each of the subfolders of `/home/a/Desktop/MyCycles/DavidSilver` .

Any idea how can I fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming GNU `find(1)`:

```bash
find /home/a/Desktop/MyCycles/DavidSilver -type d -printf '%p/bin\0' | xargs -0 mkdir
```

Withtout GNU `find(1)`, but assuming directory names don't contain newlines:

```bash
find /home/a/Desktop/MyCycles/DavidSilver -type d | \
    sed 's!$!/bin!' | \
    xargs mkdir
```

Comment: Doesn't work , I tried it and it just prints on the screen `/bin/bin/bin......` .Edit : Ok , it just stopped and indeed created the folder , but the code ran for 2 minutes .

Comment: Yes, on most filesystems directory operations are syncronous.  Nothing you can do about it (well, actually you _can_ make them async, but you shouldn't, if you care about your data).